# Sanitize the output of the_title() or the_title_attribute() to remove whitespace

Tags: title

I have an issue. I have a piece of sharing code which I created for social media.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?>.<?php the_permalink();?>" class="twitter">
```

Now when I run this through the W3 Validator it says there shouldn't be a space. Now when I looked at the code it was outputting the title DOES have spaces in it.

How do I sanitize this title to add in dashes within my url?

I just want the title to add dashes in this context only.  I have looked at the sanitize_title function and the_title_attribute function in the Wordpress Codex but don't really know how to make it work in this situation. I am sure there is a simple solution. Any help would be great.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the space to dashes using wordpress `sanitize_title_with_dashes` function Try below code.

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title(get_the_ID())); ?>.<?php get_the_permalink(get_the_ID());?>" class="twitter">
```

I have used `get_the_title()` and `get_the_content()` functions because these both function return the context instead of echo them, and i think you are concatenating the string.

Hope this help .